# Using Ubuntu command line to replace text in huge file

Tags: command-line, text, sed

I have a huge XML file that I must work with. Right now the file is only 1 line that contains about 2 million characters which represent 30,000 records. There are no carriage returns or linefeeds whatsoever. What I need to do is make each record on it's own line. New records begin with `<ROW>` and end with `</ROW>`.

I've been looking around here and it seems the tools to use are: sed, tr or awk but I'm not sure which is most appropriate.

I've tried this to no avail:

```
tr '<ROW' '\012 <ROW' <source.xml |tee destination.xml
```

Above seems to output some pretty weird stuff so I must be way off here. maybe it's that "<" character that is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `tr` can replace *sequences* of characters (just single characters at a time, albeit possibly from a *set*) - I would try something like

```
sed 's|</ROW>|&\n|g' source.xml > destination.xml
```

Comment: thanks for the response, steeldriver. i tried that but it didn't quite work. destination.xml is still one single line and has the `n` character written in after each of occurance of `</ROW>`. for example: `</ROW>n<ROW>`

Comment: Check the command you used, you must have left out the \  in  \n  above.

Comment: @Hannu. as mentioned, i tried steeldriver's suggestion and i did not omit the forward slash prior to the n in the replacement string. illustration:`$ echo "<ROW><FieldA>data1a</FieldA><FieldB>data1b</FieldB></ROW><ROW><FieldA>data2a</FieldA><FieldB>data2b</FieldB></ROW>" | sed 's|</ROW>|&\n|g'
<ROW><FieldA>data1a</FieldA><FieldB>data1b</FieldB></ROW>n<ROW><FieldA>data2a</FieldA><FieldB>data2b</FieldB></ROW>n` the new line replacement did not work. instead the letter n is being written between rows of data which remain on a single line.

Comment: same with this too:`$ echo "123row123row123row" | sed 's|row|&\n|g'
123rown123rown123rown`

Comment: @user299331 that's very strange - almost as if the single quotes are not preventing the shell from interpreting the backslash. Does `echo "123row123row123row" | sed s/row/\&\\n/g` work?

Comment: @steeldriver, no that doesn't work either: `echo "123row123row123row" | sed s/row/\&\\n/g
123rown123rown123rown` almost seems like my sed is broken if that is even possible. i think this used to work fine but after several days of messing with sed maybe something got hosed? above works for everybody else?

Comment: @user299331 or possibly something about your shell or terminal configuration

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on? And what's the output of `sed --version`? My sed is 4.2.2 and the above command works.

Answer (score 0):

If possible (eg, it's a valid xml document), I'd highly advise a tool that's intended for this job.  eg, xmllint (from the package libxml2-utils).

```
xmllint --format filename.xml
```

Comment: i installed that package and tried xmllint but it won't accept my input file. i tried this even though my data is not valid xml (just a sloppy database dump from a application by a lazy developer). thanks for the idea though, Shaun.